# According to the aws shared responsibility model, when using amazon rds, who is responsible for scheduling and performing backups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is aws responsible for both or customer is responsible for scheduling

i'm just confused i think customer is responsible for scheduling what is right answer please help

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky question because you can set automatic backups up to 35 days. If you want to access some older backups (older than 35 days), you need to take snapshots.
Nevertheless, the question looks like it's from AWS certification, so it's better to know what answer AWS wants (generally the customer is responsible for backing up).
It depends on what we consider as a 'backup' - literally (AWS - because they are responsible for making it and it's obligatory) or in a wider sense (both AWS & Customer - because they are making backups but you need to decide how often eg. 1-35 days and make occasional snapshots, if needed).

Answer (score 0):

In RDS, backup is turned on by default. You need to setup the retention based on your use-case.

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/backup/